# Change Drawables in Android Gradle External Library

Tags: android, gradle, android-drawable

Is there any way to change the drawables in an external library that has been imported with Gradle?

Every time i change the drawables in the external library they get reset whenever i build my app :(

Comment: Can you specify how do you import the library from the gradle file?

Comment: from git repo location in dependencies in the build.gradle file .  e.g:
    compile 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.2'

Comment: Try to delete the gradle cache.